# One Step Publish Not Sending Files To Correct Directory From Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, one-click-web-publishing

For some reason Visual Studio one step publishing is duplicating the initial folder files are suppose to go in, but not sure why.  Is there a bug in VS 2015 for windows application publishing

```
550 CWD failed. "/Application Files/Exposure.Cloud_1_0_0_39/Application Files/Exposure.Cloud_1_0_0_39/Application Files/Exposure.Cloud_1_0_0_39/System.Net.Http.dll.deploy": directory not found.
```

The folder I am publishing to is a share, but I FTP to it all the time via Beyond Compare just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched back from ftps to regular ftp and it worked.  Must be a port or connection issue between VS and Filezilla.